# How to get a list of all users and the number of their posts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I welcome everyone. I have two models: User, Post. They have standard connections. I need to make an Active Record request in such a way that I would immediately get a list of all users and the number of his posts. Include doesn't work because it commits all posts to memory. I somehow thought of this solution, but it does not show users who do not have posts at all.

My solution:

`User.joins(:posts).select('users.*, count(posts.id) as post_count').group('users.id')`

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you are using an INNER JOIN, thus retaining only rows where a User can be joined with a Post.

To get a list of users and a count of their respective posts, you need to use an OUTER JOIN:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:posts).select('users.*, count(posts.id) as post_count').group('users.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop over all the users you want to and get them by
`Post.where(id: user.id)`
Something along that line

Comment: It's too slow, I need to get the most optimized query. So that there are no extra requests to the database and that no extra memory is consumed. Me just need, in one query, to get all users from the database and only the number of their posts. The example I showed works, it meets my requirement, but it does not display those users who have no posts at all. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The issue here is that users with no post will not be assigned anything when you do  `select` thus why it does not show anything for users with no post. You can perhaps consider having a column specifically for `post_count` in the User. Update this column when post is created / deleted. This will also be more time saving.

Comment: Yes, I know I would, but unfortunately I don't have access to migrations Unfortunately, I need to do exactly the query

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **left_outer_join** is good advice, but you could also use the `includes` method, as Rails already provided this clever algorithm.

Under the hood, however, it will act as a left_outer_join in a more thoughtful way.

```
User.includes(:posts).select('users.*, count(posts.id) as post_count').group('users.id')
```

Here is a [nice post](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes) about *preload*, *eager load*, *includes* and *joins* with the active record if you want to use it as a reference.

With this, I think you should be able to get the post count by users, including users without posts.